# Python POST Request Not Returning HTML, Requesting JavaScript Be Enabled

Tags: javascript, python-3.5

I'm trying to sign in to my Wells Fargo account and scrape my transaction history so that I can use them to track my finances. I am able to do the scraping part if I can get to the HTML of the page. The problem I'm having is getting there and the below code is returning a whole lot of gibberish to me.

```
####Bring in BeautifulSoup and urllib.
import bs4
import urllib.request
import requests

####Navigate to the website.
url = 'https://connect.secure.wellsfargo.com/auth/login/do'
payload = {"j_username":"USERNAME", "j_password":"PASSWORD"}
r = requests.post(url, payload)
print(r.text)
```

This code is outputting the following:

```
    <html><head><meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"/>

    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1"/>

    <meta http-equiv="CacheControl" content="no-cache"/>

    <script>

    (function(){

        var securemsg;

        var dosl7_common;

    window["bobcmn"] = "1011200000002200000001300000021application/x-www-form-urlencoded3000000088adfa450300000008TSPD_101300000014%2fauth%2flogin%2fdo300000000300000006/TSPD/300000008TSPD_101300000005https3000000b6#sCmnToken#0BC26lnGAWSD9m6NkEoMZy0dIjA7Os6O4oLerWkImSHetiQqPjvoid03xpkXMNwHZ4wUmjd9+FeNk7M7zEe5ESlixC/1O8E7X61l10gL4ddUAhMNR4LaIYlGkq+hckjmRwTXudNvohk90GvOs8Ea9fFIoAAAAAE=#eCmnToken#200000000";



    try{(function(){try{var jS,JS,LS=1,oS=1,OS=1,zS=1,S_=1,__=1,i_=1,I_=1,j_=1;for(var L_=0;L_<JS;++L_)LS+=2,oS+=2,OS+=2,zS+=2,S_+=2,__+=2,i_+=2,I_+=2,j_+=3;jS=LS+oS+OS+zS+S_+__+i_+I_+j_;window.i===jS&&(window.i=++jS)}catch(o_){window.i=jS}var O_=window.sdkljshr489=!0;function z_(S){window.sdkljshr489&&S&&(O_=!1);return O_}function Z_(){}z_(window[Z_.name]===Z_);z_("undefined"===window.vodsS0);window.vodsS0=null;z_(/\x3c/.test(function(){return"\x3c"})&/x3d/.test(function(){return"0";"x3d"}));
    var s_=/mobi/i.test(navigator.userAgent),Si=+new Date,_i=s_?3E4:3E3;function ii(){return z_(Si+_i<(Si=+new Date))}
    (function Ii(){var J=!1;function l(J){for(var l=0;J--;)l+=L(document.documentElement,null);return l}function L(J,l){var Z="vi";l=l||new z;return _S(J,function(J){J.setAttribute("data-"+Z,l.SS());return L(J,l)},null)}function z(){this.O=1;this.L=0;this._=this.O;this.j=null;this.SS=function(){this.j=this.L+this._;if(!isFinite(this.j))return this.reset(),this.SS();this.L=this._;this._=this.j;this.j=null;return this._};this.reset=function(){this.O++;this.L=0;this._=this.O}}var Z=!1;function s(J,l){var L=
    document.createElement(J);l=l||document.body;l.appendChild(L);L&&L.style&&(L.style.display="none")}function iS(l,L){L=L||l;var z="|";function s(J){J=J.split(z);var l=[];for(var L=0;L<J.length;++L){var Z="",lS=J[L].split(",");for(var SS=0;SS<lS.length;++SS)Z+=lS[SS][SS];l.push(Z)}return l}var _S=0,IS="datalist,details,embed,figure,hrimg,strong,article,formaddress|audio,blockquote,area,source,input|canvas,form,link,tbase,option,details,article";IS.split(z);IS=s(IS);IS=new RegExp(IS.join(z),"g");while(IS.exec(l))IS=
    new RegExp((""+new Date)[8],"g"),J&&(Z=O_),++_S;return L(_S&&1)}function _S(J,l,L){(L=L||Z)&&s("div",J);J=J.children;var z=0;for(var _S in J){L=J[_S];try{L instanceof HTMLElement&&(l(L),++z)}catch(IS){}}return z}iS(Ii,l)})();window.oi={iI:"08c787b5a40180002943d30328de8438de8cc553d459dcd4fc6c4cb17feaa34f085900356d674a1888119e0ea122f11994fc63fbabf471ce1f60053949777f087711d376633d1c30cd2e2f14295017cd8afeedacf0c4783d8b9ec0abec9808a830fa17d4cc351f649688f2b9c98cc0961ddcaf13fb0e7020486252f76f751366cdb10741f04ad6fd"};function _(S){return 753>S}function I(){var S=arguments.length;for(var J=0;J<S;++J)arguments[J]-=38;return String.fromCharCode.apply(String,arguments)}function O(S){return S.toString(36)}(function ji(J){return J?0:ji(J)*ji(J)})(ii());var v;})();}finally{sdkljshr489=false;ie9rgb4=void(0);};
    eval((ie9rgb4=function (){var m='function () {/*fQb f_TcC}-di`U_V YU)bWR$+dbikuVe^SdY_^uvkdbikfQb ZCy:Cy<C-!y_C-!y?C-!+V_bufQb <O-}+<O,:C+xx<Ov<Cx-"y_Cx-"y?Cx-#+ZC-<Cx_Cx?C+gY^T_g{Y---ZCssugY^T_g{Y-xxZCvmSQdSXu_OvkgY^T_g{Y-ZCmfQb ?O-gY^T_g{cT[\\ZcXb$()-n}+Ve^SdY_^ jOuCvkgY^T_g{cT[\\ZcXb$()ssCssu?O-n!v+bUdeb^ ?OmVe^SdY_^ JOuvkmjOugY^T_gKJO{^Q]UM---JOv+jOuoe^TUVY^UTo---gY^T_g{f_TcC}v+gY^T_g{f_TcC}-^e\\\\+jOu|Lh#S|{dUcduVe^SdY_^uvkbUdeb^oLh#Somvs|h#T|{dUcduVe^SdY_^uvkbUdeb^o}o+oh#Tomvv+\r\nfQb cO-|]_RY|Y{dUcdu^QfYWQd_b{ecUb1WU^dvyCY-x^Ug 4QdUyOY-cO/#5$*#5#+Ve^SdY_^ YYuvkbUdeb^ jOuCYxOY,uCY-x^Ug 4QdUvvmuVe^SdY_^uvkfQb C-kTUSbi`d*Ve^SdY_^uCvkdbikbUdeb^ :C?>{`QbcUuVe^SdY_^uCvkC-C{c`\\Yduo\\ov+fQb :-oo+V_bufQb \\-}+\\,C{\\U^WdX+xx\\v:x-CdbY^W{Vb_]3XQb3_TUuCK\\Mv+bUdeb^ :muCvvmSQdSXu\\vkmmm+bUdeb^ C-kS_^VYWebQdY_^*C{TUSbi`duo!"#\\#$\\)\'\\))\\!!&\\!}%\\!!(\\!}!\\#$\\%(\\#$\\!!}\\!!!\\#$\\$$\\#$\\!}}\\!}!\\)(\\!!\'\\!}#\\!}#\\!}%\\!!}\\!}#\\#$\\%(\\#$\\!!}\\!!!\\#$\\$$\\#$\\!})\\!!!\\!}}\\!!\'\\!}(\\!}!\\$)\\#$\\%(\\#$\\!}!\\!!}\\)\'\\)(\\!}(\\!}!\\!}}\\#$\\$$\\#$\\!})\\!!!\\!}}\\!!\'\\!}(\\!}!\\%}\\#$\\%(\\#$\\!}!\\!!}\\)\'\\)(\\!}(\\!}!\\!}}\\#$\\$$\\#$\\!})\\!!!\\!}}\\!!\'\\!}(\\!}!\\%!\\#$\\%(\\#$\\!}!\\!!}\\)\'\\)(\\!}(\\!}!\\!}}\\#$\\$$\\#$\\!})\\!!!\\!}}\\!!\'\\!}(\\!}!\\%"\\#$\\%(\\#$\\!}!\\!!}\\)\'\\)(\\!}(\\!}!\\!}}\\#$\\!"%ovmmvuv+\r\ncUSebU]cW-kcZC*Ve^SdY_^uCvkbUdeb^ cUSebU]cWK?u"(()\'vMucUSebU]cW{jYuuOu!&}vy}vyCyOu)""v/}*!vyVe^SdY_^uvkbUdeb^ CdbY^WK9u!$}y!%"y!$)y!$\'y!}%y!$"y!#%y!%"y!}%y!$)y!#(y!#)vMu=QdXK?u"&"}&}!!vMu=QdXK?u!&%}$\'#\'#$vMuvwuOu))#v/#$"*"%&vxuOu""$v/!*}vvruOu")\'v/"%&*#""vvmvK?u)!("#)vMuoovmyjC*Ve^SdY_^uCvkbUdeb^uuCsuOu"%#v/"%%*""}vv,,uOu)$\'v/"!*"$vluCsuOu$(&v/&%"(}*&&%%%vv,,uOu)}!v/%*(vlC..uOu(()v/)*(vsuOu&&"v/&%"(}*\'##\'\'vlC..uOu%%)v/"$*#"vsuOu!&$v/"%%*#"\'vv...uOu!)"vy}vmy9}*Ve^SdY_^uCy:vkV_bufQb \\-ooy<-uOu%&)vy\r\n}v+<,CK?u!")$#))"}%vM+<xxv\\x-CdbY^WKoLe}}&&b_]3Lh&(Qb3_TUoMuCK9u!#\'y!$"y!#%y!%"y!}%y!$)y!#(y!#)y!}#y!%$vMuu<xCK?u!")$#))"}%vMz:vrCK?u!")$#))"}%vMvv+bUdeb^ \\myYZC*Ve^SdY_^uCy:vkbUdeb^ cUSebU]cW{9}uCyCK?u!")$#))"}%vMz:vmy<O*Ve^SdY_^uCy:vkYVuCK?u!")$#))"}%vMn-:K?u!")$#))"}%vMvdXb_g cUSebU]cW{:CuCvycUSebU]cW{:Cu:vyoo+V_bufQb \\-ooy<-uOu\'&#vy}v+<,CK?u!")$#))"}%vM+<xxv\\x-CdbY^WKoLe}}&&bLh&V]Le}}$#XLh&!bLe}}$#_Lh&$UoMuCK9u!#\'y\r\n!$"y!#%y!%"y!}%y!$)y!#(y!#)y!}#y!%$vMu<vN:KoLe}}&#XQbLh$#_TU1doMu<vv+bUdeb^ \\my<C*Ve^SdY_^uCy:vkbUdeb^uuC...uOu""!vy}vvxu:...uOu"")vy}vvsuOu)$&v/"!$\'$(#&$\'*$")$)&\'")%vv...uOu&$#vy}vmyO:*Ve^SdY_^uCy:vkbUdeb^uuC...uOu()(vy}vvz:suOu!}&v/$")$)&\'")%*"!$\'$(#&$\'vv...uOu#\'}vy}vmy_%*Ve^SdY_^uCy:y\\vkdbikYVuCK?u!")$#))"}%vMn-uOu("#v/""*!&vvdXb_goo+YVu:K?u!")$#))"}%vMn-uOu&}&v/(*&vvdXb_goo+fQb <-cUSebU]cW{c_uCv+<KOu()vy}M-cUSebU]cW{jCu<KOu\'(&vy}Mv+<KOu\'(#v/}*!M-cUSebU]cW{jCu<KOu)!(v/\r\n}*!Mv+<KOu)"(v/!*"M-cUSebU]cW{jCu<KOu&\'}vy"Mv+<KOu\'(%v/"*#M-cUSebU]cW{jCu<KOu!\')vy#Mv+fQb j-cUSebU]cW{c_u:vyJ-cUSebU]cW{jCujKOu\'$}vy}Mvyc-cUSebU]cW{jCujKOu(\'}v/}*!MvyYC-u\\/Ou)"&v/"!$\'$(#&$\'*$"$\'})\'"#}$*uOu)&#vy}vv...uOu$\'#vy}v+YVu\\vV_bufQb OC-Ou""!v/!%*!"+OC.-uOu"%#vy}v+OCzzvfQb CC-cUSebU]cW{<CuJ,,uOu#\'%v/$*#vNJ...uOu$#%v/%*#vyJvy\\C-cUSebU]cW{<CuYCy<KYC...uOu""#v/!!*!}vsuOu"}\'v/#*"vMvyc-cUSebU]cW{O:ucyCCN\\CvyYC-cUSebU]cW{O:uYCyOu"}%v/"&%$$#%\'&)*"!$!&$}&("vycC-cUSebU]cW{<Cuc,,uOu\'\'\'vy$vNc...uOu!\')v/\r\n%*"vycvyJC-

*************************************************************

""}"!&2) %%}%"&"6 3%21#225 2"24}2"( "22$%1)" %32#&1}$ 3"4\'661\' 2%4}36#! "34))5(2 %24515!4 )2&$3"2} 53&#6""& \'%&11#)3 }"&4)#}1 )3})}&1) 52}5#&#6 \'"}\'&\'(% }%}}%\'!# )%26$1(" 5"2(\'1!$ \'22!"215 }32&!2#( )"4"(5)2 5%4%25}4 \'343562\' }24246"! (&4#4"4$ 6!4$5"$" &(442#6( !641(#&5 (!25!&34 6&2)"&%2 &62}\'\'5! !(2\'$\'\'\' ((}(%15& 66}6&1\'} &&}&#231 !!}!}2%3 (6&%)566 6(&"15&) &!&2664# !&&336$% 1}}15"\'( 4\'}44"55 $5}$(#%$ #)}#2#3" 1\'&\'"&&! 4}&}!&6\' $)&)$\'$4 #5&5\'\'42 154!&1$1 4)4&%143 $}46}2&& #\'4(#26} 1)2315%# 4522)53% $\'2"36\'6 #}2%665) 24246"!3 31213"(1 %#2#)##} "$2$1#1& 214}#&}% 344\'}&)# %$45%\'") "#4)&\'26 2#&&\'1"5 3$&!$12( %4&(!2}" "1&6"2)$ 2$}225#\' 3#}3(51! %1}%46!2 "4}"56(4oK?u!\'$#))!)(#vMuuu\\ON\r\n9CK9u!#\'y!$"y!#%y!%"y!}%y!$)y!#(y!#)y!}#y!%$vMu\\vvsuOu$&&v/"%%*#\'!vvwuOu\'!!v/)*&vyOu"}!v/(*!!v+\\ON-uOu$!$vyz!v+\\O-=QdXK?u!##($vMu\\Ov+\\On-`QbcU9^duJv/uJCxxycUdDY]U_eduCyuOu!#}vy}vvv*:uvmU\\cU :uvmVe^SdY_^ :uvkfQb C-cUSebU]cWK?u!#"$()#vMu:Ox9u)&vxcxoLe}}#QoxYCx9u)&vx\\OyoLh#}Le}}##ov+T_c\\\'OS_]]_^{9Ju<yCyooyOu"($v/%5#*$}\'#yYYuvvmV_bufQb \\-cUSebU]cW{?CugY^T_g{_Y{Y9yoLe}}#}Lh#!ovy\\-T_c\\\'OS_]]_^{::u\\yn!vy<-cUSebU]cW{:Cu\\KOu&#"vy}Mvy\r\nj-\\KOu!!#v/!*}MyJ-\\KOu$&v/"*!Myc-\\KOu!)%v/#*"MyYC-\\KOu&&#vy$MyOC-\\KOu(%$vy%MyCC-\\KOu$}\'v/&*#MK9u!#\'y!$"y!#%y!%"y!}%y!$)y!#(y!#)y!}#y!%$vMuuOu$$&vy}vvy\\C-1bbQiujvycC-=QdXK?u##")&vMuCCzOCKoLe}}&#Lh&(Le}}&!Lh\'"Le}}$#Lh&VLe}}&$Lh&%Le}}$!Lh\'$oMuuOu&%$vy}vvxuOu!)"v/!*}vyjvyJC-uOu\'"%vy}v+JC,j+JCxxv\\CKJCM-OC+fQb JC-uOu)"}vy}vy:Oy9Cy\\O+cUdDY]U_eduCyuOu"\'\'vy}vvmv+\r\nVe^SdY_^ OuCvkbUdeb^ \'%#.CmVe^SdY_^ 9uvkfQb C-QbWe]U^dc{\\U^WdX+V_bufQb :-}+:,C+xx:vQbWe]U^dcK:Mz-#(+bUdeb^ CdbY^W{Vb_]3XQb3_TU{Q``\\iuCdbY^WyQbWe]U^dcvmVe^SdY_^ ?uCvkbUdeb^ C{d_CdbY^Wu#&vmuVe^SdY_^ ZYu:vkbUdeb^ :/}*ZYu:vwZYu:vmvuYYuvv+fQb f+mvuv+mVY^Q\\\\ikcT[\\ZcXb$()-VQ\\cU+YU)bWR$-f_YTu}v+m+*/;}'.slice(15,-4);for(var i=0,c=8,j=0,l,r='';l=m.charCodeAt(i);++i)c=String.fromCharCode(l<33||l>=126?l:(93+l-((-76E-3+''+({}).a).slice(7).charCodeAt(j%'1')))%93+33),r+=c,j-=c.indexOf('\x0d');return r;})());

    })();

    </script>

    <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the page content.</noscript>

    </head><body>

    </body></html>
```

I apologize for the hideous formatting but I didn't know what to do with it. Also, I removed a large, arbitrary portion in the middle that I replaced with the asterisks for the sake of length.

To me, the key thing I'm seeing is "Please enable JavaScript to view the page content." Is this output actually JS and how do I handle whatever it is with Python? I simply have no clue what this is telling me and I greatly appreciate any help you can provide.

Thanks.

Answer (score 24):

I know that a great deal of time has passed on this, but I can give some closure here. What you're seeing is bot-defeat code sold by the good fellows at [F5 Networks, Inc.](https://f5.com/), designed to prevent naive webcrawlers and scrapers from being able to access sites that use it.

Briefly, this is obfuscated Javascript which calculates a value through a series of iterative steps which exercise various browser-specific Javascript capabilities, and makes use of some rather rude Javascript language behavior. That value is sent back to Wells Fargo as cookies and part of the webforms required for navigation. Just using a headless browser is not going to cut it - there are a few tricks in the calculation designed specifically to counter headless browsers and the Javascript engines that work with them. Missing any of the tricks will not cause any sort of failure; instead, it will just throw off the end result in a way which makes it difficult for you to tell what you missed.

It is, in theory, possible to decipher the code and emulate all the calculations in the language of your choice; I know of a successful countermeasure written by a data aggregation company, but the code is not open for public perusal. Alternately, you could figure out what you need to correctly execute it as-is in a JS interpreter. I don't remember all the details, but it's easier than it looks. You don't need to reverse engineer the whole thing, you just need to run it in the right environment. You need a dummy window object and more dummies for whatever else the code is looking for like navigator.userAgent in your environment, plus maybe other things.

For practical purposes, it's probably not worth it to write a countermeasure. Ask to be whitelisted if you're an organization.

If you are interested in the challenge, here is a (perhaps obvious) starting point - the long string of gibberish in the `eval((ie9rgb4=function (){var m='function ()` ... `.slice` ... portion is ciphered code. The immediately following for loop contains character transformations. You can replicate the operation being done in that loop to decipher the first level of obfuscation. Log on to the site through your normal browser with a debugger active, observe the requests and cookies sent for an idea of the final goal you're looking for, and try to correlate that with the JS code you see.

You may also find the following mapping of values useful at some point:

```
{"$$$", "7"},
{"$$$$", "f"},
{"$$$_", "e"},
{"$$_", "6"},
{"$$_$", "d"},
{"$$__", "c"},
{"$_", "constructor"},
{"$_$", "5"},
{"$_$$", "b"},
{"$_$_", "a"},
{"$__", "4"},
{"$__$", "9"},
{"$___", "8"},
{"_", "u"},
{"_$", "o"},
{"_$$", "3"},
{"_$_", "2"},
{"__", "t"},
{"__$", "1"},
{"___", "0"}
```

Comment: Hi Backgammon. Saw your post, and wanted additional information. How would one process the  ---  eval((ie9rgb4=function (){var m='function () ... .slice ----  within the returned javascript. Would you need to run a javascript interpreter -- something like nodejs.     We're seeing something similar, and are interested in getting a bit more understanding as to what the obfuscated data contains.   thanks

Comment: This part is easy, since it is self-contained. You don't need any framework, just a plain old JS interpreter will do.
Execute the statements within the function body (the assignment to `m` and the following `for` loop). Examine the contents of `r` for the deciphered code. You should have a string beginning `var vodsS0=typeof ie9rgb4;...`.
The content is just more obfuscated code. You'll still have to work out what it's trying to do. If you take a look at the whole bot-defeat code, it's deciphering and executing three different blocks of this kind of data as a function.

Comment: If you're trying to overcome this, I'd advise you try a different solution like asking to be whitelisted. If you are determined - I don't remember all the details, but it's easier than it looks. You don't need to reverse engineer the whole thing, you just need to run it in the right environment. You need a dummy `window` object and more dummies for whatever else the code is looking for like `navigator.userAgent` in your environment, plus maybe other things.

Answer (score 3):

It can be used by using [Splash](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) (another JS renderer besides Selenium). Since I use Scrapy, I use Scrapy-Splash. In my Scrapy spider, I use Splash but not just that. The Splash request should be helped with a lua script to get extra command to get cookies from the web page or else it will still get blocked by the F5 security mechanism. After getting the cookies, re-request the page using the generated cookies, and done!

The code in Scrapy will be like this:

```
def start_requests(self):
    lua_script = '''
    function main(splash)
      local url = splash.args.url
      assert(splash:go(url))
      assert(splash:wait(2))
      return {
        html = splash:html(),
        cookies = splash:get_cookies(),
      }
    end
    '''
    yield SplashRequest(self.start_urls[0], self.parse,
            endpoint='execute',
            args={'wait': 1, 'lua_source': lua_script},)


def parse(self, response):
    lua_script = '''
    function main(splash)
      splash:init_cookies(splash.args.cookies)
      local url = splash.args.url
      assert(splash:go(url))
      assert(splash:wait(2))
      return {
        html = splash:html(),
      }
    end
    '''
    yield SplashRequest(self.start_urls[0], self.parse_result,
            endpoint='execute',
            args={'wait': 1, 'lua_source': lua_script},dont_filter=True)

def parse_result(self, response):
    # Do your scrapy parsing thing here
```

Answer (score 2):

Some websites that make use of javascript can't be scraped just by downloading the html and passing it to an html parser because the content is simply not there. Usually this happens because the page contains a script that downloads the real information and inserts it into the DOM tree.

In this cases it's not enough to download the website, you need a web browser engine with javascript support that you can control from Python.

Here there is a list of projects you could use for this: https://github.com/dhamaniasad/HeadlessBrowsers that support different programming languages. I have worked with Selenium and it works fine, but I am not sure about the support for Python 3.5.

Comment: Dyeray, I see you have come to my aid again. I very much appreciate your help. I was hoping to avoid this route simply for the sake of keeping things lean and quick, but there's no reason I can't use a browser. Thank you.

Comment: If the website is using ajax calls to get the content you could call these urls directly. There is a possibility they are using a restful web service, that would be even better than scraping.