# send post request and get a reply (python and postman)

Tags: python, ubuntu, web-hosting

When I send post request to my php file with **requests.post** in python (I have also tried postman and I got the 
  same result)

When I send the request to my ubuntu server It works well and I get a reply
   When I send to the same PHP file in my localhost (XAMPP)   It works well and I get a reply

**BUT** :  When I try to send the same request to the same php file but to my website **(ON FREE HOSTING)**

I get the following reply

ïn postman :

`This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support`

in python :

```
    <html>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js"></script>
    <script>
        function toNumbers(d) {
            var e = [];
            d.replace(/(..)/g, function(d) {
                e.push(parseInt(d, 16))
            });
            return e
        }

        function toHex() {
            for (var d = [], d = 1 == arguments.length && arguments[0].constructor == Array ? arguments[0] : arguments, e = "", f = 0; f < d.length; f++) e += (16 > d[f] ? "0" : "") + d[f].toString(16);
            return e.toLowerCase()
        }
        var a = toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),
            b = toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),
            c = toNumbers("3ae379a8f951fdbd269738b26c4c3d93");
        document.cookie = "__test=" + toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c, 2, a, b)) + "; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/";
        location.href = "http://somefreehosting/php/register.php?i=1";
    </script>
    <noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript>
</body>

</html>
```

I want to show the javascript message in my ubunto server Instead of executing the request to protect from bots

Comment: Are you viewing the response as HTML in postman, rather than as raw text?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python POST Request Not Returning HTML, Requesting JavaScript Be Enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34707532/python-post-request-not-returning-html-requesting-javascript-be-enabled)

Comment: @byxor preview . the raw replay is similar to the  Python replay

Comment: @GovindaMalavipathirana Unfortunately no